# Module 'firebase_analytics' not found when archiving ios(Flutter app)

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-analytics

I have been trying to archive my ios app for days but i keep getting this error. When i run in debug mode though, it builds successfully.
I've done these repeatedly but still no hope:

- Adding `GoogleService-info.plist` via xcode
- `Flutter clean`
- Deleted `podfile, podfile.lock, symlinks`
- `Flutter pub get`
- `pod install &&pod repo update`
- Launch `Runner.xcworkspace` in xcode

**My podfile**

```
platform :ios, '11.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

**Firebase packages im using**

```
  firebase_core: ^0.5.3
  firebase_analytics: ^6.3.0
  firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^0.6.3
```

Comment: First of all make sure you have opened Runner.xcworkspace file. Then follow this https://medium.com/@azpm95/integrate-flutter-project-with-firebase-efb687dd5e8#:~:text=Download%20the%20config%20file.,into%20that%20android%2Fapp%20subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue, here's what worked for me:

Add this in `Pod file`

```
target 'Runner' do
 pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
end
```

Comment: I Still have the issue